# Correct translation of "would have"

Tags: españa, verbos-auxiliares

In the sentence

> If you had told us the price, we **wouldn't have** bought it

which of these is correct?

> Si nos hubiéras dicho el precio, no lo **hubiéramos comprado**

or

> Si nos hubiéras dicho el precio, no lo **habríamos comprado**

Thanks!

Comment: They are both correct.  I believe this has already been asked and answered.  Check your spelling, though -- e.g. *hubieras*.

Comment: Yeah, it has been. It's been found and tagged as such. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ¡Bienvenido al sitio!